# Thread synchronization with Clojure

Tags: multithreading, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I got an exercise:

- Print in order all positive integers from 1 to 100.
- Using blocks, semaphores or other similar mechanisms (but avoiding sleep), coordinate two threads such that the combined output from both threads appears in numerical order.

  ```
   Sample Output
      In thread one: The number is ‘1’
      In thread two: The number is ‘2’
      In thread one: The number is ‘3’
      In thread two: The number is ‘4’
  ```

The exercise is for Ruby, but I'd like to show to my class that Clojure could be a good option for the task.

I don't have any experience with threads in any language, but I was thinking to use something like:

```
 (def thread_1 (future (swap! my-atom inc) ))
 (def thread_2 (future (swap! my-atom inc) ))
```

but **@thread_1** always returns the same vale. Is there a way to coordinate two threads in Clojure?

I found this [example](https://javadiscover.blogspot.com/2018/06/printing-oddeven-using-2-threads-in.html) in Java using ReentrantLock and Condition, and now I'm trying to translate it to Clojure.

Comment: Does the order matter? I mean threads should work one after another, like in your example.

Comment: @fl00r, yeah, the order must be sequential.

Answer (score 4):

If the order of threads does matter and if you are curious about non-classical thread communication, you could go with `clojure.core.async` and use "channels".

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as a])

(let [chan-one (a/chan 1)
      chan-two (a/chan 1)]
  (a/>!! chan-one 1)
  (doseq [[thread in out] [["one" chan-one chan-two]
                           ["two" chan-two chan-one]]]
    (a/go-loop []
      (when-let [n (a/<! in)]
        (if (> n 10)
          (do (a/close! in)
              (a/close! out))
          (do (prn (format "In thread %s: The number is `%s`" thread n))
              (a/>! out (inc n))
              (recur)))))))
```

The output is

```
"In thread one: The number is `1`"
"In thread two: The number is `2`"
"In thread one: The number is `3`"
"In thread two: The number is `4`"
"In thread one: The number is `5`"
"In thread two: The number is `6`"
"In thread one: The number is `7`"
"In thread two: The number is `8`"
"In thread one: The number is `9`"
"In thread two: The number is `10`"
```

One gotcha here is that go-routines are executed in a thread pool, so they are not dedicated threads, and if you want to use real threads you should go this way:

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as a])

(let [chan-one (a/chan 1)
      chan-two (a/chan 1)]
  (a/>!! chan-one 1)
  (doseq [[thread in out] [["one" chan-one chan-two]
                           ["two" chan-two chan-one]]]
    (a/thread
      (loop []
        (when-let [n (a/<!! in)]
          (if (> n 10)
            (do (a/close! in)
                (a/close! out))
            (do (prn (format "In thread %s: The number is `%s`" thread n))
                (a/>!! out (inc n))
                (recur))))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

First, the reason you're seeing odd results is you're dereferencing the `future`, not the atom holding the number. The future will return the result of `swap!` when dereferenced.

Second, you can use `locking` (basically Java's `synchronized`) to only allow one thread to increase and print at a time:

```
(def n-atom (atom 0))

(defn action []
  ; Arbitrarily chose the atom to lock on.
  ; It would probably be better to create a private object that can't be otherwise used.
  (locking n-atom
    (println
      (swap! n-atom inc))))

(defn go []
  ; Have each thread do action twice for a total of four times
  (future (doall (repeatedly 2 action)))
  (future (doall (repeatedly 2 action))))

(go)
1
2
3
4
```

I'll note though that `future` really shouldn't be used here. `future` is for when you want to compute a result asynchronously. It swallows errors until it's dereferenced, so if you never `@`, you'll never see exceptions that come up inside the `future`. It would be better to use a thread pool, or, with the help of a macro for ease-of-use, start up two threads yourself:

```
(defmacro thread
  "Starts the body in a new thread."
  [& body]
  `(doto (Thread. ^Runnable (fn [] ~@body))
         (.start)))

(defn go []
  (thread (doall (repeatedly 2 action)))
  (thread (doall (repeatedly 2 action))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to generally coordinate multiple threads operating on the same state using an [agent](https://clojure.org/reference/agents):

```
(def my-agent (agent 1 :validator #(<= % 100)))
(future
  (while true
    (send my-agent
          (fn [i]
            (println "In thread" (.getName (Thread/currentThread))
                     "the number is:" i)
            (inc i)))))
In thread clojure-agent-send-pool-4 the number is: 1
In thread clojure-agent-send-pool-5 the number is: 2
In thread clojure-agent-send-pool-5 the number is: 3
In thread clojure-agent-send-pool-4 the number is: 4
In thread clojure-agent-send-pool-4 the number is: 5
In thread clojure-agent-send-pool-4 the number is: 6
```

You'd see the same essential behavior here with or without the `future` because `send` returns immediately in the inner loop, and the *sent* function may be executed on different threads in the pool. The agent takes care of coordinating access to the shared state.

**Update:** here's another way to do the same thing that doesn't involve a `:validator` function, or termination by exception:

```
(def my-agent (agent (range 1 101)))
(while (seq @my-agent)
  (send
    my-agent
    (fn [[n & ns]]
      (when n
        (println "In thread" (.getName (Thread/currentThread))
                 "the number is:" n)
        ns))))
```

Comment: The information here is not wrong, but … using a validator for ordinary termination? Letting the future crash on ordinary termination? Well, the example could be improved.

Comment: @glts fair point! See updated answer and let me know if you can think of other improvements.